# Multiple joins rails confusion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have the following

```
**User** model
has_many orders class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"


**Order** model
has_many :items, class_name: "OrderItem"


**OrderItem** model
belongs_to :orderable, -> { with_deleted }, polymorphic: true
```

So a **User** has many **Orders**, each **Order** contains many **OrderItems**, and they have an "orderable_id" related to a product_id

I'm trying to return a list of User ids of users who have NOT purchased a certain item

Currently, i have

```
User.joins(:orders => :items).where("orders.status = 'success'").where("order_items.orderable_id != ?", product_id).pluck(:id)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't go deep enough.

It is successfully discarding the OrderItem if it contains the offending product_id, but i need to to discard the User entirely if ANY of the OrderItems contain the offending product_id

it's just a bit over my head

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word in MySQL. This will cause you grief in due course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
user_who_purchased_ids = User.joins(orders: :items).where("orders.status = 'success'").where("order_items.orderable_id = ?", product_id).pluck(&:id)
users_who_did_not_purchase = User.where('id not in ?', user_who_purchased_ids)
```

Comment: i get a TypeError can't quote array when i try to use that .. - tried just passing the ids and i get a syntax error

Comment: @BryanSpence please share the code maybe it is something else now

Comment: i haven't changed anything - i have it just as you mentioned above. when i include the user_who_purchased_ids in the "id not in ?" line i get TypeError - can't quote Array

Comment: so using  User.where.not(id: users_who_purchased_ids) fixes this, but the request seems to be too large - causes the server to time out